# Review within Product or Product within Review?

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I'm trying to add structured data to **reviews of third-party products**. Think of the typical little blogger reviewing a camera she just bought, for example.

So the article is a review of a **widely available product**, with **one rating** provided solely by the author.

I don't understand if the main `itemType` should be `Product` or `Review`, with the other element nested inside (using the properties `review` or `itemReviewed` respecitvely).

I'd say the main type should be `Review` as the author is not the product manufacturer, but Google says [this](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review-snippet):

> Refer clearly to a specific product or service by nesting the review within the markup of another schema.org type

I'm confused... and very thankful if anyone can shed some light!

Answer (score 1):

On product page X -

- Review writer - some person
- Long Article is the `reviewBody`(reviewBody is a `Review` Property)
- `reviewRating` = 4 of 5

Schema Example from this site:
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.techradar.com%2Fin%2Freviews%2Fasus-rog-strix-gl-10cs-gaming-desktop

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ 
   "@type":"Product",
   "name":"Asus ROG Strix GL 10CS gaming desktop review",
   "image":"https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/EbueaZpQR6PQFFHqVPfWJD.jpg",
   "brand":"asus",
   "mainEntityOfPage":{ 
      "@type":"WebPage",
      "@id":"https://www.techradar.com/in/reviews/asus-rog-strix-gl-10cs-gaming-desktop"
   },
   "url":"https://www.techradar.com/in/reviews/asus-rog-strix-gl-10cs-gaming-desktop",
   "review":{ 
      "@type":"Review",
      "name":"Asus ROG Strix GL 10CS gaming desktop review",
      "reviewBody":"Asus ROG Strix GL 10CS is an entry-level gaming desktop by the Taiwanese electronics maker. Made for enthusiasts, the GL 10CS is the first full tower CPU in the Strix series of products with a capacity of 27 liters. The gaming desktop packs in the latest 9th generation Intel processor coupled with NVIDIA&rsquo;s RTX goodness for a great gaming experience at a budget. It&rsquo;s upgradable and has illuminating RGB lighting spread across the front that gives the desktop a cosmetic touch. We spent some&hellip;",
      "headline":"Asus ROG Strix GL 10CS gaming desktop review",
      "alternativeHeadline":"Great gaming experience on a budget!",
      "datePublished":"2019-08-30T12:22:47Z",
      "keywords":[ 
         "Asus ROG gaming desktop",
         "newstrack",
         "review",
         "newstrack",
         "review"
      ],
      "thumbnailUrl":"https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/EbueaZpQR6PQFFHqVPfWJD-320-80.jpg",
      "creator":{ 
         "@type":"Person",
         "name":"Siddharth Chauhan"
      },
      "publisher":{ 
         "@type":"Organization",
         "name":"TechRadar",
         "url":"https://www.techradar.com",
         "logo":{ 
            "@type":"ImageObject",
            "url":"https://vanilla.futurecdn.net/techradar/media/img/techradar_logo.png",
            "caption":"TechRadar logo"
         }
      },
      "author":{ 
         "@type":"Person",
         "name":"Siddharth Chauhan"
      },
      "reviewRating":{ 
         "@type":"Rating",
         "ratingValue":"4",
         "bestRating":"5"
      }
   },
   "description":"Great gaming experience on a budget!",
   "@context":"http://schema.org"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch is right. Look at the simple review example and you will see a review containing the item reviews.

Read the rest of your quoted sentence that continues with "or by". It relates to the scenario where the review contains the item reviewed.

> or by using a schema.org type as a value for the itemReviewed
>   property.